# What is the perfect way to get response from docusign api webhook response in php?

Tags: webhooks, docusignapi

I have set a web hook URL for docusign API. when any update from document signer come, i will get update about envelop. but how can i get the response? What is the format. Can someone show me a example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to receive and process webhook notifications from DocuSign Connect, you'll need to create an application to "listen" for (and process) the notifications. DocuSign provides sample applications like this in a variety of languages -- you can use this link to find those samples on GitHub:  https://github.com/docusign?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=connect.

For example, here's the webhook sample in PHP: https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-php.

Answer (score 0):

You will get response from DocuSign in an XML format, You can find more details at https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-adding-webhooks-application/,
https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/connect-technical-details.htm and Guide is available at https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/connect-guide.pdf